# Can't remap "Expo" in CompizConfig for 13.04

Tags: compiz, 13.04, expo-mode

Currently, the shortcut for Expo (showing all workspaces) is <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>.  I can change the shortcut in the Compiz Settings manager, however, no shortcuts that I set work for Expo.

In fact, even if I set different keyboard shortcuts, <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> continues to work. Why isn't the shortcut changing?

Comment: Maybe a bug. report it.

Comment: I have opened a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1173451